# Getting installation probllem in installing Discord

Tags: software-installation, java

```
unable to install discord:
    Error while installing package: installed oracle-java11-installer-local package 
    post-installation script subprocess returned error exit ststus 1
```

I have downloaded .deb file from internet and got the error.not only discord I got same problem while installing some softwares.

so thanks in advance.

Keval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two alternatives:

- If you do not plan to use Oracle Java 11 then run

  ```
  sudo dpkg -P --force-all oracle-java11-installer-local
  sudo dpkg -P --force-all oracle-java11-set-default-local
  ```
- If you want to get Oracle Java 11 installed then run

  ```
  sudo apt-get install curl
  sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
  curl -L -b "oraclelicense=a" -O https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11.0.12%2B8/f411702ca7704a54a79ead0c2e0942a3/jdk-11.0.12_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
  sudo mv jdk-11.0.12_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install oracle-java11-installer-local
  ```

and then retry Discord installation:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://dl.discordapp.net/apps/linux/0.0.15/discord-0.0.15.deb
sudo apt-get install ./discord-0.0.15.deb
```

Comment: Another alternative: Discord is also available as a Snap: `sudo snap install discord`

Comment: Thankyou @N0rbert

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

Sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install snap

sudo snap install discord

Comment: Your content is totally correct but I have some Java incomplete installation . So I get error while installing other application